# Bash variable in rename regex

Tags: regex, bash, rename, batch-rename

I'm writing a bash script to rename files names and using command

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d", $&)/e' *
```

But would like to replace "%02d" with something like "%0"$var"d" thus replacing '2' with $var but it seems like it doesn't work and I'm not well versed in regex and how to use escape \ and would like help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, your whole expression is inside single quotes where no expansion is performed. To expand a part of the command, move it out of the quotes:

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%0'"$var"'d", $&)/e' *
```

Or put the whole expression in double quotes, but then you'll need to escape more:

```
rename "s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%0${var}d\", \$&)/e" *
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer , can you drop a link to learn about escape characters?

Comment: I usually simply type `man bash` or google for something like https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash when unavailable.

Comment: Ohk will check it out

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass the value via the environment

```
env var=5 rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%0$ENV{var}d", $&)/e' *
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is $ENV recognized inside single quotes?

Comment: Yes. With the perl rename, inside single quotes is a perl expression, and $ENV{var} is the perl way to access environment variables. What's more, because we need perl to evaluate that variable, we require it to be in single quotes (or else we need to escape it from the shell)